# SQL query to compare value of a field for two different dates

Tags: mysql, compare

I have a table this this:

```
Date    Name    Rating
01-Dec-14   Ash A
02-Dec-14   Ash A
03-Dec-14   Ash AA
04-Dec-14   Rob BB
05-Dec-14   Rob BB
06-Dec-14   Charly  A
07-Dec-14   Charly  AA
```

I just to write a sql query which gives me date/name/ratings where rating has changed between the dates. To be more precise, I want to know when is the rating change happend for which names for a period of time.

THanks a lot.

Comment: I think we have to maintain history table against rating

Comment: This won't be possible with a "simple SQL Query", because there is no way with simple SQL to compare between rows. You'll need cursors or a programm to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to enumerate the rows using variables and then aggregate:

```
select name, rating, min(date) as firstdate, maxdate(lastdate)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@nr = concat_ws(':', name, rating), @grp,
                        if(@nr := concat_ws(':', name, rating), @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from table t cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @nr := '') params
      order by name, date
     ) t
group by name, grp, rating;
```